# Nested Tablix Data Sources

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to have a tablix within another tablix.  Is it possible to change the nested tablix's data source, because Visual Studio 2008 is not letting me for some reason...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you'll have to create a subreport and nest the subreport in the tablix